# Is there a way to scroll down an Instagram page using a scraper?

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler

This is a function I wrote to **scrape** the image URLs from my Instagram profile.

```
def ImageList():
    url = 'https://www.instagram.com/Username/?hl=en'
    data = req.Request(url)
    resp = req.urlopen(data)
    respData = resp.read()

    dat = re.findall(r'"src"\s*:\s*"(.+?)"', str(respData))

    print(str(respData))
    i = 0
    rec = []
    for x in dat:
        if re.search("/s640x640/", x):
            rec.append(x)
    return rec
```

Though it works quite well, it just returns the top 9 URLs or so. I realized it was because the page itself is an infinite scroll page, thus I need to scroll the page to load all the Images and get their URLs.

Is there a was to do it without using drivers (Selenium Webdriver) i.e. write my own code for it.

I know Instagram has an API, the goal here is to make my code self sufficient,  please don't bombard me with that, thank you.